# Is this column load bearing?

Tags: framing, structural, load-bearing

I want to remove the pony wall, the floor to ceiling column that separates the kitchen from the family room. I have oodles of original plans, and I don't see any obvious-to-me indicators that this column is load bearing, however at the same token I don't see anything that tells me it is NOT load bearing. Help?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: My advice, if you are not sure, is to hire a local professional to assess the situation. This is a safety issue and you would be very foolish to rely on opinions from a website based solely on drawings whose origin is unknown.

Comment: This also sounds like work that would require permitting in any jurisdiction, so you could potentially bring the floor plans to the permitting office and ask them. From the joist direction, it's unlikely load bearing, but it doesn't mean that the specific column in question *isn't*.

Comment: I have no desire to bank on something a webcrawler says, particularly without logical justification, and it does make sense to pay a local professional to determine the answer to my question. Still, I'm simply asking if anyone out there knows if the answer lies in these drawings. If it does, could you provide an explanation. If it doesn't, thanks!

Comment: It looks to me like the joist are running from top to bottom in the second picture. This usually means that there isn't much weight in that area, as the ends of each ceiling joist would be holding all of the weight. However, getting a view up inside of the ceiling would be helpful in determining what areas are load bearing, and what areas are not. Let me know what you come up with!

Comment: I don't think anyone here can say definitively that it isn't load bearing. The drawing *seems* to indicate that it isn't, but it may be exceptional.

Answer (score 2):

Several things suggest that it's not load bearing:

- The fact that it's at the end of a "pony wall". This is likely a horizontal support post that wouldn't be present if not for the wall.
- The wording "to ceiling". This suggests no structural integration with the roof framing or any supporting member.
- The lack of blocking or other load-transfer notes in the floor framing layout.

Some things that would seal the deal:

- Footing layout showing no supporting structure at this location, and...
- Main floor truss diagrams showing no concentrated load below the post.

With what's presented here I can only be about 98% certain. If you want more than that, consult a local professional.

Comment: +1 for looking for possible footing...